# logging a coroutine aware variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-asyncio

I'm following the worker example given in `asyncio.Queue`. In functions called by `worker_task()` I'd like to log the current worker name without having to pass it everywhere.

I suspect through some combination of `LoggerAdapter` and `ContextVar` it can do what I want.

Something along the following...

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(worker_name)s %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def sub_function():
    logger.info("a message") # worker-1: a message

async def worker_task(queue, worker_name):
    logger.do_something(worker_name) # HELP HERE PLEASE
    await sub_function()

queue = asyncio.Queue()

workers = [
    loop.create_task(worker_task(queue, "worker-1"),
    loop.create_task(worker_task(queue, "worker-2"),
]
```

Comment: Please *always* use a generic [python] tag for Python questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
import logging
import asyncio
from contextvars import ContextVar

WorkerName = ContextVar('worker_name')

logging.basicConfig(format='%(worker_name)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class WorkerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('extra', {})['worker_name'] = WorkerName.get()
        return msg, kwargs

logger = WorkerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), None)


async def sub_function():
    logger.info('a message')

async def worker_task(worker_name):
    WorkerName.set(worker_name)
    await sub_function()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

workers = [
    loop.create_task(worker_task('worker-1')),
    loop.create_task(worker_task('worker-2')),
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*workers))
```

Comment: Nice! A bit fussy since I had things in multiple files but this works a treat. Thanks.